# JS / PHP : redirection in browser history

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm trying to do the following:
A user interacts with a page test.php, clicks on a button and is redirected to redirect.php. Before redirecting him, I store the final page (page.php) in a cookie.

On redirect.php, if the user is passing through for the first time, I redirect him to page.php after xx ms, I read the cookie to know to which page the user has to be redirected.
I want redirect.php to be visible in the browser history so that when the user clicks on back, I can do something before he leaves and he should not be redirected to page.php

To redirect the user from redirect.php to pages.php, I use the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
if ((isset($_COOKIE["redirect_count"])) && ($_COOKIE["redirect_count"]==0))
    {
        setcookie("redirect_count",1,time()+84600);
        setcookie("redirect_passed",1,time()+84600);
        $redirect_url = $_COOKIE["redirect_url"];
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function()
    {   

        window.location.assign("<?PHP echo $redirect_url; ?>");
    }, 100);
</script>
<?PHP       
    }   
else
    {

// do something else
    }
?>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

In short, first visit:
test.php => click on button => redirect.php => page.php
Any other visit or back in history
page.php => redirect.php => other action

If I create the redirect_url cookie manually and access redirect.php in my browser, I'm correctly redirected to page.php and I see redirect.php in my browser history. When clicking on back I can do something else than redirecting the user back to page.php. I use redirect_count to make sure the user doesn't go back to page.php in case he goes back in history.

If I access the redirect.php from another page and load it into my browser with a window.open in JS, the redirection to page.php works but I don't see redirect.php in my browser. Of course the cookie redirect_url is created before hitting the button on test.php.

Why is the redirection behaviour different ? How can I ensure that I have the same behaviour from a window.open? Or is there another way to do that?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example. I use Firefox, when I open the redirection page with the `window.open` function, I can see it laying in the go-back dropdown.

Comment: @shingo yes I forgot to mention that it works with Firefox but not with Chrome (desktop or mobile)

Comment: I tried with Edge. I find that if you click the page anywhere before redirecting, it will keep the address. I also tried `.focus()` and `.click()` but they didn't work. So I guess this should require more native system messages. Perhaps you need to ask the developers of chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Heyy..I hope this will work for your concern..

```
 echo "<script>
        setTimeout(function()
        {   
    
            window.location.assign("$redirect_url");
        }, 100);
    </script>";
```